# MySQL: Error while reverse engineering database from a sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, hsqldb, radix

I'm trying to reverse engineer a DB in MySql with a sql file generated from an OpenOffice database.
while trying to import and run the sql file, I get the following error:

```
    ERROR: Line 1: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting EVENT_SYM or FUNCTION_SYM. Statement skipped.
```

I tried many a things including removing double quotes and adding delimiter to the statements, yet the issue persists. 
For your reference, please find the excerpts from the .sql file.

```
    CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA;
    CREATE CACHED TABLE Users(UserID NUMERIC(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,FirstName VARCHAR(50),LastName VARCHAR(50),MobileNumber VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,EmailAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,CompanyName VARCHAR(50),City VARCHAR(50),StateOrProvince VARCHAR(50),CountryOrRegion VARCHAR(50),PostalCode INTEGER,PassPhraseID NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL,Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,Age NUMERIC(3) NOT NULL,MaritalStatus CHAR(10),Height NUMERIC(4,1),Weight NUMERIC(3),Complexion INTEGER,PreferredMessageMode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,isPaid BOOLEAN NOT NULL,FBID VARCHAR(50),BBM VARCHAR(8),PreferredVerticals VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(100),EmergencyNos CHAR(60) NOT NULL,DOB DATE,PhotoID INTEGER,CategoryID NUMERIC(2) NOT NULL,isActive BOOLEAN NOT NULL,ActivationDate TIMESTAMP(0));
    CREATE CACHED TABLE UserLocation(UserID NUMERIC(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,Location NUMERIC(22) NOT NULL,Timestamp TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT SYS_FK_101 FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID));
```

I have no clue about this.
Please help,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you can get more help on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks @Kuzgun for directing me to the right place. :)